# How to uninstall/remove the package from dist-packages?

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-packaging

I have two directories in container. One is to save dist-package and another one to save site-package. There are similar packages in both the directories but with different versions.

```
# Print the contents of site-packages in the virtual environment
RUN cd /home/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages && ls -lR

# Print the contents of site-packages in the system-wide installation
RUN cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages && ls -lR
```

The certifi library present in both the directories are having different versions. The dist package contains old version of certifi library i.e. **certifi==2019.11.28** and site-packages contains newer version **certifi==2023.07.22** as I am trying to upgrade the version in dockerfile by writing a command RUN pip install --upgrade certifi==2023.07.22.

Although both these libraries are not conflicting each other and the container is running well despite having two versions. But I need to remove the older version because Lacework Scan showing this version as Vulnerable. I tried to uninstall the package by writing PIP UNINSTAL command and also mention the target path but this approach is not working. Could somebody provide way to resolve this issue?

Comment: you need to remove it using your distribution's package manager

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: How to find out the distribution's package manager? If it's not PIP. Did you mean apt-get for Ubuntu 20.04(As I am using Ubuntu). Do I need to update the package using apt-get instead of pip?

Comment: I wonder if `pip install certifi`, not using a virtual environment, will upgrade the system package.  If dated dependencies will intrinsically be a problem, you also might see if you can upgrade to a newer version of the base image (what is your current `FROM` line?).

Comment: Yes it is apt-get, this is often knowledge that comes for free with using a linux distro. Note that the system package is probably there for a reason, maybe a dependency, so if no update is available, do not change it, maybe you will break something.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using pytorch/torchserve:latest image.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I used apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.9 \ certifi but it's not working. In dist-packages, it is still showing me the older version of certifi library.

Comment: I recommend you provide a full standalone [mre].